# Jquery dynatree do no react on first click on a radio button

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, dynatree

I use the click function to move an edit menu next to the radiobutton in a rails application. It works fine except for that the first click on a radiobutton has no effect. The second click and another or the same buton, however, moves the menu. That happens for each expanded submenu too.

Any help would be very much appreciated

Here is some of the code

```
 $("#document_tree").dynatree({
         checkbox: true,
          classNames: {checkbox: "dynatree-radio"},
          selectMode: 1,
          onActivate: function(node) {

                if( node.attr("href") ){
                    window.location.href = node.attr("href"); }
          },
          onSelect: function(select, node) {
            var selectedNode = node;
                $("#show_button").attr("href","/documents/"+selectedNode.data.key+"?documented_type=<%=@documented_type%>");    
                $("#edit_button").attr("href","/documents/"+selectedNode.data.key+"/edit"+"?documented_type=<%=@documented_type%>");    
                $("#new_folder_button").attr("href","/documents/new?id="+selectedNode.data.key+"&kind=folder"+"&documented_type=<%=@documented_type%>");
                $("#new_document_button").attr("href","/documents/new?id="+selectedNode.data.key+"&kind=document"+"&documented_type=<%=@documented_type%>");
                $("#new_link_button").attr("href","/documents/new?id="+selectedNode.data.key+"&kind=link"+"&documented_type=<%=@documented_type%>");
                $("#destroy_button").attr("href","/documents/"+selectedNode.data.key+"?documented_type=<%=@documented_type%>");
```

// here is where I use the click function to find the radio buttons coordinates. I have tried to put this code in many other places but it works only here

```
            $(".dynatree-radio").click(function(e){
               var mouseX=e.pageX;
               var mouseY=e.pageY-10;
            $("#tree_menu").css({left:'25px',top:mouseY});
                });

      },
```

Sorry for bothering you with this question. I found the solution in last attempt to google.
The solution was to use
    $(".dynatree-radio").live('click', function(e){
instead of just 
'        $(".dynatree-radio").click(function(e){